# Regex is not working in RegularExpression attribute on c#

Tags: c#, regex, model-view-controller

guys, I don't know this question is already present or not but I have tried every search, so my question is why my regex is not working properly in RegularExpression attribute. this same regex I have used in javascript and this is working on javascript. can anyone help me what I am doing wrong here?

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "First name")]
[MaxLength(50)]
[RegularExpression("^(?![@\\+\\-=\\*])", ErrorMessage = "First Name Should not start with these characters @, +, =, *, -")]
public string firstname { get; set; }
```

I am using this regex for validating the First Name should not start with @,+,=,*,-.

I have already spent 3 hours to figure out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Take into account that those two have different regex engines, and you may encounter certain discrepancies.

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`? Did your validator not trigger on client side at all? or the regex is not validating as expected?

Comment: Your Regex expression is failing. You can test Regex expressions here: http://regexstorm.net/tester

Comment: @DarjanBogdan I have tested this regex using Regex class I think this is working on C# but I am using RegularExpression attribute for the first time so I don't know how it is work.

Comment: @Zeeshan is triggering but it's not working as I expected. it's not allowing anything .

Comment: @Oystein this website using js regex engine so please remove one \ then it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you regex should look like this:

```
^(?![@\\+\\-=\\*]).*
```

[Here is a working example.](https://dotnetfiddle.net/92XF2k)

Comment: thanks, this is working like charm can you tell me what I was doing wrong?

Comment: @ManishTiwari basically you haven't add `.*` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is invalid. Here is the updated one, which works as you expected:

```
^(?![@\\+\-\\=\\*])
```

Comment: teo van kot answer is working. let me test yours as well