# Regex is not working in c# but working in javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, model-view-controller

I am trying to validate string should not start with some character and should not contain <>.

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "First name")]
[MaxLength(50)]
[RegularExpression(@"(?=(^(?!.*[><]).*$))(?=(^(?![@\+\-=\*]).*))", ErrorMessage = "firstname"+ Constants.DisplayMessage)]
public string firstname { get; set; }
```

this regex is working in javascript. but it is not working in c#. I have already spent almost 1 hours on it but no result please help me.
ya also tried using `(^(?!.*[><]).*$)|(^(?![@\+\-=\*]).*)` this regex.but it is not working.
I am not good at regex so please help me.

Comment: What is this regex for? What do you expect from _$_ in the middle of expression?

Comment: Please give some background for what this regex is supposed to be doing.  It may even be that you could use a simpler pattern in both places.

Comment: @AlexSeleznyov you can use https://regexr.com/  it will help you to understand what I am trying to do.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen cannot contain < or > and cannot start with @, -, =, * characters

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295781/regex-is-not-working-in-regularexpression-attribute-on-c-sharp Please check this answer once, it may help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description what the regex needs to do, the following pattern should work:

```
^(?![@=*-])(?!.*[<>]).*$
```

Explanation:

```
^
(?![@=*-])    from the start of string, assert that @=*- is not the first character
(?!.*[<>])    also assert that <> does not appear anywhere in the string
.*            then match anything (our assertions having be proven true)
$
```

### Demo

This pattern is also working for C#, as you can see by exploring the second demo below.

### C# Demo

Comment: thank you, I am testing it on my c# code give me 5 min.

Comment: it is working on javascript but not working on c#. and you are testing it on javascript regex engine.

Comment: in c# I am using RegularExpression Attribute.

Comment: @pravaljain The pattern seems to work fine for me in C#.  Have a look at the demo I added to my answer.  My guess is that you are using one of their APIs incorrectly.

Comment: thanks, Tim but for your demo, I replaced your regex with mine and my is also working but I don't know why it is not working on the attribute. I think I am using API incorrectly.

Comment: @pravaljain Maybe you could ask a specific C# question with a working pattern and ask why your code isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Having proper set validator, it works in C# too
public class NameProp 
{
    string m_firstname;

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "First name")]
    [MaxLength(50)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?![@=*-])(?!.*[<>]).*$", ErrorMessage = "firstname contains <> or start with @=*-")]
    public string firstname
    {
        get { return m_firstname; }

        set
        {
            Validator.ValidateProperty(value,
                new ValidationContext(this, null, null) { MemberName = "firstname" });
            m_firstname = value;
        }
    }
```

}

public class Program
    {

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NameProp np = new NameProp();
        try
        {
            np.firstname = "<>JJ";
        }
        catch (ValidationException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Also please refer https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/550784/Validation-using-DataAnnotations for more details