# ASP.NET Core [RegularExpression] validation fails, even though the regex is demonstrably correct

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-core, validation

I have the following method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsersAPICall([Bind(nameof(query))] [RegularExpression(@"^\w+(\.\w+)*@\w+(\.\w+)+|(\w+(\s\w+)*)|[a-z0-9]+$", ErrorMessage = "This does not look like a valid query")] string query)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
       return BadRequest();
    }
}
```

This fails for email addresses like `test-def.ghi@de.jkl.com` (but *not* for email addresses like `test@test.com`).

I know for a fact that the regex is the correct pattern, because the following LINQPad script displays `True` as expected for the exact same email address:

```
void Main()
{
    var r = new Regex(@"^\w+(\.\w+)*@\w+(\.\w+)+|(\w+(\s\w+)*)|[a-z0-9]+$");
    
    r.IsMatch("test-def.ghi@de.jkl.com").Dump();
}
```

I tried dropping the `[Bind(nameof(query))]` entirely, but that didn't help.

If I change this to

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetUsersAPICall([Bind(nameof(query))] string query)
{
    if (!Regex.IsMatch(query, @"^\w+(\.\w+)*@\w+(\.\w+)+|(\w+(\s\w+)*)|[a-z0-9]+$"))
    {
        return BadRequest();
    }

    // ...
}
```

I'm completely baffled as to why what I had originally wasn't working. Can someone see what I'm missing here?

The closest I've found so far on Stack Overflow is [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48295781/regex-is-not-working-in-regularexpression-attribute-on-c-sharp), but there it turned out that the OP's regex was wrong (which isn't the case for me, since the Regex works just fine in two different contexts).

Comment: "*I know for a fact that the regex is the correct pattern*": I don't think [this](https://regex101.com/r/9ezYLz/1) is your expected result...

Comment: @InSync I'm confused, then - the same pattern appears to have worked in LINQPad. Am I missing something dumb?

Comment: I don't know ASP.NET/C#, so I'm not sure what you are trying to match. If it's email addresses you're after, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5342375). The main problem is that the pipes (`|`) in your regex are dividing the expression, making `^` only applies to the first part and `$` the last. Perhaps you meant to enclose those parts in a group (`^(...|...|...)$`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is within your regex and difference in its handling by `IsMatch` and `RegularExpression` annotation.

`IsMatch` checks if input contains anything matching provided regex.
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=net-7.0#system-text-regularexpressions-regex-ismatch(system-string-system-string-system-text-regularexpressions-regexoptions-system-timespan)):

> Indicates whether the specified regular expression finds a match in the specified input string, using the specified matching options and time-out interval.

So it's trying to find any match in your input, finds it (specifically for second alteration: `(\w+(\s\w+)*)`) and returns true.

`RegularExpression` annotation on the other hand checks if your whole input matches provided regex. [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute?view=net-7.0#remarks):

> The regular expression searches for an exact match, not using `^` before and `$` at the end of the pattern produces the same results as using it. For a search hit, prepend and append the pattern with `.*`.

So effectively, annotation applies pattern `^(?:^\w+(\.\w+)*@\w+(\.\w+)+|(\w+(\s\w+)*)|[a-z0-9]+$)$`.

Probably you tried to achieve similar effect, but forgot parenthesis?

Comment: Good point, thanks. I was really confused.